# passenger issue with cloud66 deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, cloud66

when i deployed using cloud66 I got this:

First time this happened:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while starting your web application. Because you are running this web application in staging or production mode, the details of the error have been omitted from this web page for security reasons.

Please read the web server error log to find the details of the error. If you don't know where the web server error log is, read the troubleshooting documentation below.

Alternatively, you can turn on the "friendly error pages" feature (see below), which will make Phusion Passenger show many details about the error right in the browser.

Phusion Passenger troubleshooting documentation:

Nginx integration mode
Apache integration mode
Standalone mode
To turn on friendly error pages:

Nginx integration mode
Apache integration mode
Standalone mode: pass the --friendly-error-pages parameter to the passenger command.

### error log for nginx:

```
nginx_error.log — inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:3:in `require'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:1:in `new'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:1:in `<main>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
nginx_error.log — [ 2015-06-21 15:40:59.0770 20448/7ffa7a1e4700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 21] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is ef14968e. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
nginx_error.log — [ 2015-06-21 15:40:59.0774 20448/7ffa7a1e4700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 37] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is ef14968e. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
nginx_error.log — App 24023 stdout:
nginx_error.log — App 24023 stdout:
nginx_error.log — [ 2015-06-21 15:41:05.2655 20448/7ffa7c2ca700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
nginx_error.log — Error ID: ec59ece6
nginx_error.log — Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-7YDCgc.html
nginx_error.log — Message from application: /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/app/controllers/discuss_topics_controller.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/app/controllers/discuss_topics_controller.rb:173: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:3:in `require'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:1:in `new'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:1:in `<main>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
nginx_error.log — [ 2015-06-21 15:41:05.2733 20448/7ffa7a1e4700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 21] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is ec59ece6. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
nginx_error.log — App 24047 stdout:
nginx_error.log — App 24047 stdout:
nginx_error.log — [ 2015-06-21 15:41:16.1314 20448/7ffa7c2ca700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
nginx_error.log — Error ID: 698a7033
nginx_error.log — Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-jNWPnk.html
nginx_error.log — Message from application: /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/app/controllers/discuss_topics_controller.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/app/controllers/discuss_topics_controller.rb:173: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:3:in `require'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:1:in `new'
nginx_error.log — config.ru:1:in `<main>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
nginx_error.log — /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
nginx_error.log — [ 2015-06-21 15:41:16.1387 20448/7ffa7a1e4700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 21] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 698a7033. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
nginx_error.log — [ 2015-06-21 15:41:16.1394 20448/7ffa7a1e4700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 38] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 698a7033.
```

Please see earlier logs for details about the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at your error log, and it seems your Passenger instance can't start due to an issue in your application:

```
nginx_error.log — Message from application: /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/app/controllers/discuss_topics_controller.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
nginx_error.log — /var/deploy/inrtracker_production/web_head/releases/20150621153940/app/controllers/discuss_topics_controller.rb:173: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Could you please take a look at those lines, and ensure the conditionals are closed?

Siavash

Comment: Please create your own question.

Comment: Thank you Siavash. That was correct. I found it on Sunday luckily.